# Windows backup to ext3 to NTFS & file/path name length limits

Tags: files, backup, ntfs, restore

I backup a work laptop to a home Ubuntu server (16.04.3). I backup the server to an external drive which came formatted in ntfs and I didn't change it. At any rate, I've not gotten errors when copying from the Win laptop to Ubuntu. But when removing the external drive and plugging it into another Win PC and attempt to copy that backup back onto Ubuntu, I get an error that the file/path names are too long in some instances.

Why did Ubuntu allow me to copy it without error?

How is it apparently being restored to full length on the backup?

And if Ubuntu allowed me to copy it the first time without error, why is it giving me an error when being restored from the external, ntfs backup drive from a Win PC?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the type of backup, copy/paste may not be the best solution. If just copying personal files without regard for permissions, no problem. But if backing up entire folder structures or an entire partition there are specific tools for that.

Comment: Welcome to Windows! Windows is a multifaceted operating system; among its many faces, *there are two different maximum pathname lengths*. One maximum length is enforced by Win32, the most usual API used by userland Windows programs; and another maximum length, much larger, is enforced by the file system. Note that there are many Windows programs which will happily go beyond the 255 character maximum length enforced by Win32, because the enforcement is not serious and there is a *documented* way (using `\\?\pathname`) to go past it; for example, use Total Commander to copy the files.

Comment: You really should not back up files to a ntfs partition with copy. You can put the files in a tar archive and copy the .tar to the nfs drive. The problem is ntfs is not going to preserve ownership or permissions or path length

Comment: Thank you all. The laptop is Win10 64-bit. The server is Ubuntu 16.04.x. The copy command is simply copy/paste from the Windows laptop. The data is backup up nightly, using rsync, to the external, ntfs-formatted backup. Again, no errors when copy/pasting. But detaching the external drive, attaching it to another windows PC and trying to "restore" to an Ubuntu server 16.04.x yields the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this problem because generally Windows limits the whole path of a file to 255 characters, even though the actual limit on Linux is 1024.

I don't think this is really an Ubuntu issue, though.

If you want to backup your data, you should consider using Dejà Dup which ships with Ubuntu and has many useful features.

Comment: I've seen extensively that the file/path-name limit in ext3 & ext4 partitions is 255 characters. But I never got the error when copying from the Win10 64-bit laptop to Ubuntu's partitions.

Comment: @Kazz file name and path name are two different things. :)

Answer (score 0):

I regret that I wasn't able to get back to this post until now. I had a health issue and am just now getting back to my desk! As the limit of ext3 & ext4 partitions is 255 characters, I've decided to begin using a backup utility that will store all the files, compressing them and managing them, in a single file, such as Syncback.

Thanks for your input!